# How do you enable the navigation of methods and classes within a python module in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, pydev

I'm running eclipse photon with the pydev plugin installed and on the left in the pydev package explorer window you can collapse and expand folders and choose files to view in the editor.  Before I could also click on a python module that I had created and quick jump to the methods and classes inside the module by expanding the module itself without having to manually scroll inside the module's contents.  Now, however, this feature seems to be disabled upon closing eclipse and restarting it.  How do I re-enable this feature?  I've checked the preferences up and down and can't seem to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to window -> show view -> outline, that will give you a list of methods in a separate view and then you can click on the method you want to navigate to by selecting it in the outline view. If that does not work, reset your perspective by going to window -> perspective reset.

Comment: So yes I do know about the outline view however this shows as a separate window. What eclipse did was kind of combine the outline view and PyDev package Explorer view into one where you could collapse and expand folders but also collapse and expand modules to module's associated classes and methods all in one view. –

Answer (score 0):

You mean seeing the outline in the `PyDev package explorer`? It seems to work for me... can you provide a screenshot showing the case where it's not working?

Note: To see the outline and go to a method/class when the editor is open you can use `Ctrl+O` (which will show a quick outline) or use the outline view.